# How long are Entities persited?

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to understand how JPA works. From what I know, if you persist an Entity, that object will remain in the memory until the application is closed. This means, that when I look for a previously persisted entity, there will be no query made on the database. Assuming that no insert, update or delete is made, if the application runs long enough, all the information in it might become persistent. Does this mean that at some point, I will no longer need the database?

**Edit**

My problem is not with the database. I am sure that the database can not be modified from outside the application. I am managing transactions by myself, so the data gets stored in the database as soon as I commit. My question is: What happens with the entities after I commit? Are they kept in the memory and act like a cache? If so, how long are they kept there? After I commit a `persist`, I make a `select` query. This select should return the object I persisted before. Will that object be brought from memory, or will the application query the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA can't work with only the persistence context (L1 cache) or the explicit cache (L2 cache). It always needs to be combined with a datasource, and this datasource typically points to a database that persists to stable storage.

So, the entity is in memory only as long as the transaction (which is required for JPA persist operations) isn't committed. After that it's send to the datasource.

If the transaction manager is transaction scoped (the 'normal' case) then the L1 cache (the persistence context) is closed and the entities do not longer exist there. If the L1 cache somehow bothers you, you can manage it a bit explicitly. There are operations to clear it and you could separate your read operations (which don't need transactions) from write operations. If there's no transaction active when reading, there's no persistence context, an entity becomes never attached and is thus never put into this L1 cache.

The L2 cache however is not cleared when the transaction commits and entities inside it remain available for the entire application. This L2 cache must be explicitly configured and you as an application developer must indicate which entities should be cached in it. Via vendor specific mechanisms (e.g. JBoss Cache, Infinispan) you can put a max on the number of entities being cached and set/define so-called eviction policies.

Of course, nothing prevents you from letting the datasource point to an in-memmory embedded DB, but this is outside the knowledge of JPA.

Comment: I didn't mean to delete the database. I am trying to understand if _after_ a commit all those entities will remain in memory and act like a cache. I need some information very often. That is why I do not want to make a query to the database every time. Would a List create redundancies in the application itself?

Comment: If you don't want to make a query every time, you can configure the L2 cache, and optionally the query cache. In rare situations you can also opt to take advantage of the extended persistence context, which keeps the L1 cache open for an application specified duration, but this is tricky so try the L2 first ;)

Answer (score 5):

Not really. Think about it.

Your application probably isn't the only thing that will use the database. If an entity was persisted once and stored in memory, how can you be sure that, let's say, one hour later, it won't be changed by some other means? If that happens, you will have stale data that can harm logic of your application.

Storing data in memory and hoping that everything will be alright won't bring any benefits. That's why data stored in database is your primary source of information, and you should query it every time, unless you are absolutely sure that a subset of data won't change.

Answer (score 4):

When you persist an entity an entity this will add it to the persistence context which acts like a first level cache (this is in-memory). When the actual persisting happens depends on whether you use container managed transactions or deal with transactions yourself. The entity instance will live in memory as long as the transaction is not commited, and when it is it will be persisted to the database or XML etc.

Comment: So, after a transaction, all objects get deleted and only the data in the database remains?

Comment: Yes, that is almost correct. However, if you still got a reference to the entity object that you persisted through with the entitymanager you will still have it in memory though. However when the transaction ends no further syncronization of the state will be reflected in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Persistence means in short terms: you can shut down your app, and the data is not lost.

To achieve that you need a database or some sort of saving data in a way that it's not lost when you shut down the app.

Answer (score 3):

To "persist" an entity means to actually save it in the data base. Sure, JPA maintains some entity information in memory in the persistence context (and this is highly dependent on configuration and programming practices), but at certain point information will be stored in the data base - for instance, when a transaction commits, or likely (but not necessarily) after `flush()` or `merge()` operations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your entities after committing and for a select query,  you need to use the query cache. Just Google around on that term and it should be clear to you.